# Detached react-native expo project, "config.h" not found xcode project

Tags: xcode, react-native, npm, react-native-ios, expo

I have problem resolving issue "config.h not found" when running .xcworkspace project after pods are installed.

I ejected from expo using npm run eject

Then I ran pod install inside ios dictionary

Can not build the project due to mentioned error. Already tried all the tips mentioned in forums.
[Screenshot from xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be75V.png)

Comment: Clear project and try again. may should work this.

Comment: Do you really think I have not tried this at least 1000 times?